# Tornado + momoko

Tags: windows, tornado, momoko

I'm using latest Tornado (4.0.2) on MS Windows and momoko.
When I run multiple requests at the same time, I expect that the execution time of each does not exceed 10 seconds, but it is not so.
What's wrong with this code?

```
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application, url
from tornado.gen import coroutine
import tornado.httpserver
import momoko


class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return self.application.db

class HelloHandler(BaseHandler):
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        try:
            cursor = yield momoko.Op(self.db.execute, 'SELECT pg_sleep(%s);', (10,))
            self.write('Query results: %s<br>\n' % cursor.fetchall())
        except Exception as error:
            self.write(str(error))

        self.finish()

def make_app():
    return Application([
    url(r"/", HelloHandler)
    ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = make_app()

    app.db = momoko.Pool(
    dsn='dbname=sandbox user=postgres password=postgres '
        'host=localhost port=5432', size=4)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(8888, 'localhost')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Why it waits until the end of the first request?

Comment: Hello, Newbie. I think maybe your question should be bit a more especific if you want to receive some help from the communtity.

Comment: Hello, Bonifacio. What do you mean?

Comment: I think you should narrow your question. For instance, identify where your bottleneck is, describe what you expect and what is happening instead.

Comment: It's very simple. As I wrote above, I expect that some requests will be executed simultaneously, in reality, they are executed sequentially. First request latency was 10 seconds, second request latency was 10 + N seconds, etc.

Comment: I'm a little progress.
This behavior occurs only when making requests to the same URL.
I.E. requests for the exactly same URL performed synchronously.